# getting ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

I am new to yeoman and all the tools it uses. I have created a test project in yeoman and trying to run the test spec in jasmine. 
I have installed the jasmine plugin using cmd:

**npm install grunt-contrib-jasmine --save-dev**

Added a jasmine task in Gruntfile.js

```
jasmine: {
        src:    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
        specs: 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
    },
```

when i run the jasmine task **grunt jasmine** i get following error:-

```
E:\Personal Projects\yeoman-projects\test-app>grunt jasmine
Running "jasmine:src" (jasmine) task

Testing jasmine specs via phantom
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular at
..\..\..\E:\Personal%20Projects\yeoman-projects\test-app\app\scripts\app.js:3

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular at
..\..\..\E:\Personal%20Projects\yeoman-projects\test-app\app\scripts\controll
ers\main.js:3
```

Following is my main.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testAppApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  });
```

and app.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('testAppApp', [
  'ngRoute'
])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

Am i missing something ?

Thanks,
Parikshit

Comment: This problem can also occur when you include angular from `https://code.angularjs.org/`. Instead include it locally or from the Google hosted libraries API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

under jasmine src you have to include angular.js. For now you have only included you own scripts. If you are using yeaoman, they are usally in a folder called bower_components/angular.

Comment: Also make sure you reference angular.js before your own application script files

Answer (score 0):

To keep your test files clean you should use `options.vendor` for that.

```
jasmine: {
    src:    '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
    specs: 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js',
    vendor: 'path/to/angular.js'
},
```

[See the documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jasmine#optionsvendor).